# Prove Product rule by Caratheodory’s Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $I$ be an interval, let $c\in I$ and let $f,g : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at $c$. By Caratheodory’s theorem there exist functions $φ,ψ : I \to \mathbb{R}$ which are continuous at $c$ and with $φ(c) = f′(c)$ and $ψ(c) = g′(c)$ such that for all $x \in I$ we have
$$f(x) = f(c) + φ(x)(x − c), g(x) = g(c) + ψ(x)(x − c).$$

Use these representations to prove the product rule i.e. prove that $fg$ is differentiable at $c$ and that 
$$(fg)′(c) = f′(c)g(c) + f(c)g′(c).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$f(x)g(x)=f(c)g(c)+\biggl(f(c)\psi(x)+g(c)\phi(x)+\phi(x)\psi(x)(x-c)\biggr)(x-c)\ .$$ Now analyze the large parenthesis when $x\to c$, and appeal to the other direction of Caratheodory's theorem.

Comment: The large bracket $B$ is a combination of continuous functions, therefore continuous, and therefore $f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable. Its derivative at $c$ by definition is $B(c)$. Noting that at $c$ the third term is zero, this is then $f(c)\psi(c) + g(c)\phi(c) = f(c)g'(c) + f'(c)g(c)$.